# PHP watermark with imagecopyresampled function

Tags: php, watermark

Is it possible to make a watermark effect on images with `imagecopyresampled` function instead of the `imagecopy` function?

My research didn't land on good examples, so if someone can respond to my question I will be very thankful.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
$temp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($temp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($temp, $path,100);
imagedestroy($temp);
```

Comment: [A helpful response](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php)